# Hiding an element on click when it is more than one but slide up when it's just one

Tags: jquery

Trying to use the **.hide** method to hide an element when multiple of its type exist but slide it up when only one exist with **.slideUp**.  E.G Hide the one that visible when X is clicked and show the next one but slide up when the one that is visible is the last one.

The block of code below is what I've tried but it didn't work. It still hides when it's only one, it doesn't slide up. Any Ideas on how I can achieve that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   if($('.alert-box').length < 2 && $('.alert-switch').click(function () {

                 $(".alert-box:visible").slideUp(); 


}));

   });
```

```js
// onLoad events starts here  //
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".drop-down-plates  ul li:first-child").addClass('drop-down-link-headers');
  $("#nav-bar > ul li:not(':nth-of-type(1)')").addClass('hc');
  $(".alert-box").last().addClass("last");
  $(".alert-box").first().addClass("first");
  $(".alert-box:first").show();
});


// Alert Box Navigator clicks code loop starts here

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".alert-box").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });
  $(".alert-right-arrow, .alert-count").click(function() {
    if ($(".alert-box:visible").next().length != 0)
      $(".alert-box:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
      $(".alert-box:visible").hide();
      $(".alert-box:first").show();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $(".alert-left-arrow").click(function() {
    if ($(".alert-box").prev().length != 0)
      $(".alert-box").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
      $(".alert-box").hide();
      $(".alert-box").show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});





// Alert Box switch condition code starts here

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.alert-box').length > 1) {
    $(".alert-switch").click(function() {
      $('.alert-box:visible').hide().next().show();

    });
  }
});


$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($('.alert-box').length < 2 && $('.alert-switch').click(function() {

    $(".alert-box:visible").slideUp();


  }));

});
```

```css
.alert-box,
.no-more {
  height: auto;
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.no-more {
  background-color: #29568F;
  background-image: url(images/black-twill.png);
  text-align: center;
}
.alert-box.yellow {
  background-color: #FCF8E3;
  color: #D83F26;
}
.alert-box.red {
  background-color: #D64024;
  color: #fff;
}
.alert-box.blue {
  background-color: #6EBAEC;
  color: #fff;
}
.alert-left-arrow,
.alert-right-arrow {
  width: 5%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.60;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.alert-box.red .alert-left-arrow,
.alert-box.red .alert-right-arrow,
.alert-box.red .alert-switch,
.alert-box.blue .alert-switch {
  color: #fff;
}
.alert-box.yellow .alert-left-arrow,
.alert-box.yellow .alert-right-arrow,
.alert-box.yellow .alert-switch {
  color: #D83F26!important;
}
.alert-content {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 25px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.alert-content h5 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.alert-left-arrow:hover,
.alert-right-arrow:hover,
.alert-switch:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.alert-box .alert-right-arrow {
  left: 55px;
}
.alert-switch {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: -15px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  width: 25px;
  height: 13px;
  padding: 20px 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9;
  color: inherit!important;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0.40;
}
.alert-switch,
.alert-count {
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0.40;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.red .alert-switch,
.red .alert-count {
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
.yellow .alert-switch,
.yellow .alert-count {
  border: solid 1px #D64024;
  color: #D64024;
}
.blue .alert-switch,
.blue .alert-count {
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
.no-clicks {
  pointer-events: none!important;
  opacity: 0.20;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
/** Alert Count CSS **/

.alert-count {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 80px;
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px 5px 12px 5px!Important;
}
.alert-count:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
/** Alert Navigator Styling starts here **/

.alert-navigator {
  width: 920px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 25px 5px 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alerts">
  <div class="alert-box red">

    <div class="alert-switch">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- End Alert Switch -->

    <div class="alert-content">
      <h5>Very important alert!</h5>
      bzds Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuv sdgag r adipiscing elit. Curabitur quam augue, vehicula quis Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Curabitur quam augue, vehicula quis</div>
    <!-- End Alert Content -->
    <div class="alert-navigator">
      <div class="alert-left-arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
      </div>
      <!-- End Left Arrow -->
      <div class="alert-right-arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
      <!-- End right Arrow -->
      <div class="alert-count"></div>
      <!-- End Alert Count -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Alert Nagigator -->

  </div>
  <!-- End Alert Box -->

  <div class="alert-box yellow">

    <div class="alert-switch">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- End Alert Switch -->

    <div class="alert-content">
      <h5>Very important alert!</h5>
      bzds Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuv sdgag r adipiscing elit. Curabitur quam augue, vehicula quis Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Curabitur quam augue, vehicula quis</div>
    <!-- End Alert Content -->
    <div class="alert-navigator">
      <div class="alert-left-arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
      </div>
      <!-- End Left Arrow -->
      <div class="alert-right-arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
      <!-- End right Arrow -->
      <div class="alert-count"></div>
      <!-- End Alert Count -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Alert Nagigator -->

  </div>
  <!-- End Alert Box -->


  <div class="alert-box blue">

    <div class="alert-switch">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- End Alert Switch -->

    <div class="alert-content">
      <h5>Very important alert!</h5>
      bzds Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuv sdgag r adipiscing elit. Curabitur quam augue, vehicula quis Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Curabitur quam augue, vehicula quis</div>
    <!-- End Alert Content -->
    <div class="alert-navigator">
      <div class="alert-left-arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
      </div>
      <!-- End Left Arrow -->
      <div class="alert-right-arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
      <!-- End right Arrow -->
      <div class="alert-count"></div>
      <!-- End Alert Count -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Alert Nagigator -->

  </div>
  <!-- End Alert Box -->



</div>
```

Comment: you don't have to have mastered in Jquery. Use an IDE like notepad++ or other program with syntax highligting and you will realise all stuff within `.read()`can be summerised into one. Btw., another small improvement is, that you can move the script block into the head section. The `$(document).ready()`is responsible that the included code will executed, when the DOM is ready loaded (see JQuery's documentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fskz7rcj/4/

---

```
// Alert Box switch condition code starts here
$(".alert-switch").on("click", function(){
    if($(".alert-box:visible")[0] === $(".alert-box:last")[0])
        $('.alert-box:visible').slideUp(1000, function(){
            $('.alert-box').first().show();
        });
    else $('.alert-box:visible').hide().next().show();
});
```

---

Comment: Sorry... now it does what it should (I think)... Hope this helps

Comment: @Wasgington The only one I want to slide up is the last one or when there's only one alert. I want others to just close.